# Как установить курсор на запись с введенным ID в SQLite

Tags: android, java, sqlite

Добрый день! Имеется таблица с записями в sqlite. В Активити я должен вывести запись на экран в подготовленную форму по ее id. Но как мне это сделать?

Как установить курсор на нужную запись и дальше считывать поля в переменные?

[Примерно так выглядит форма вывода записи.](http://s019.radikal.ru/i626/1405/bd/8a407fc88fa0.png)

Вот так это работает сейчас, конечно совсем не правильно.

```
ID = Edt_ID.getText().toString(); // получаем введенный id 
int id = Integer.parseInt(ID); // преобразование в из строки в число 
Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);                                 
if (c.moveToPosition(id)) {
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "recordid = " + String.valueOf(c.getPosition()));
int dateColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("date");
int monthColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("month");
int yearColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("year");
```

....
и так далее

Answer (score 1):

```
db.query(
    "mytable" /* table */,
     new String[] { "name" } /* columns */,
    "id = ?" /* where or selection */,
    new String[] { "john" } /* selectionArgs i.e. value to replace ? */,
    null /* groupBy */,
    null /* having */,
    null /* orderBy */
);
```

В вашем случае примерно так:

```
Cursor c = db.query("mytable", new String[] { "date", "month", "year" } , "id = ?" ,  new String[]{id}, null, null, null);
```